# how to build openssl in windows xp for wince 6.0

Tags: openssl, fips

Need help in building OpenSSL library for the wince 6.0 for x86.

Steps I tried

1. downloaded openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz from http://www.openssl.org/source/
2. unzipped the openssl package.
3. from the command promt under directory "openssl-1.0.1e" tried running 
    a. Perl  Configure VC-CE
    b  ms\do_ms.bat
    c. nmake -f ms\cedll.mak

trying to build the OpenSSL in WindowsXP using visual studio 2005

Answer (score 0):

> Need help in building OpenSSL library for the wince 6.0 for x86.

The OpenSSL wiki recently added a page at [FIPS Library and Windows Mobile 6](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/FIPS_Library_and_Windows_Mobile_6) (I'm fairly certain they are equivalent problems).

There's too many steps for me to copy something into place, so I kind of need to leave that as a link only. Sorry about that.